# How to write a refined type regex in scala for a string with values 1-9

Tags: regex, scala, refined

I have a string literal which is being sent to a method. The method has a type-safe parameter which takes a string.

The type-safe parameter is supposed to contain `a` as first letter
Then any number except zero.

I have written a matcher in refined types in scala

```
import eu.timepit.refined.string.MatchesRegex
import eu.timepit.refined._



type versionRegex = MatchesRegex[W.`"""a\\d?"""`.T]
type version = String Refined versionRegex
```

The problem with this is that it accepts a number from 1 to 9
Say 
`a1`, `a2` etc. Unfortunately `a0` is also supported. I want to avoid `0`

Is there a way to strengthen the regex ?

Comment: Replace `\\d` with `[1-9]`.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The answer referenced by @WiktorStribiżew is a general overview of regular expressions and does not answer this specific question.

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude 0 explicitly (this is specially useful if you want to exclude a number which is not at the beginning or at the end of the range)

```
a(?!0)\d?
type versionRegex = MatchesRegex[W.`"""a(?!0)\\d?"""`.T]
```

Or just specify which numbers you want to allow:

```
a[1-9]?
type versionRegex = MatchesRegex[W.`"""a[1-9]?"""`.T]
```